# Color to grayscale on hover not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, grayscale

I'm using [Gray](https://github.com/karlhorky/gray) for a few elements on the site. However, I can't get it to work in IE11. For example, in the fiddle below, I use JS to add the `grayscale` and `grayscale-fade` classes so that the image fades from color to grayscale on hover. How would I get this to work in IE11? The author says that the plugin needs to be initialized for IE11 (i.e. `$('article.project img').gray();`), but if I add that line, all of the images turn gray by default from the start. I just want this to work in IE11. Can someone show me how?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/61jcam54/

HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <article class="project">
        <img width="375" height="375" src="http://i.imgur.com/jNkpAg6.gif" alt="image-title">
        <div class="overlay" style="margin-left: -1px; width: 367px;">
            <h3>Project Title</h3>
            <a class="post-link expand" href="http://google.com">+</a>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

CSS

```
article.project {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1% 2%;
  max-width: 375px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

article.project img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

article.project .overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.hover .overlay, .active .overlay, .hover-sticky .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}

article.project .overlay h3 {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  font-family: 'Montserrat',sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin-top: 3.3em;
  padding: 0 1em;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}

article.project .overlay .expand {
  border: 5px solid #FFF;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 60px;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  width: 60px;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  -ms-border-radius: 30px;
  -o-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

/* GRAYSCALE */
.grayscale, .grayscale-sticky {
    /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter id='grayscale'><feColorMatrix type='matrix' values='0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");

    /* IE 6-9 */
    filter: gray;

    /*
    Chrome 19+,
    Safari 6+,
    Safari 6+ iOS,
    Opera 15+
    */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.grayscale.grayscale-fade {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter .2s;
}

.grayscale.grayscale-off,
article:hover .grayscale.grayscale-fade {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: none;
}

.grayscale.grayscale-replaced {
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: none;
}

.grayscale.grayscale-replaced > svg {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease;
    transition: opacity .2s ease;
}

.grayscale.grayscale-replaced.grayscale-off > svg,
article:hover .grayscale.grayscale-replaced.grayscale-fade > svg {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

JS

```
$('#content').on('mouseenter', 'article.project', function(){

    $(this).addClass('hover grayscale grayscale-fade');
    $(this).find('.post-link').hide();

}).on('mouseleave', 'article.project', function(){

    $(this).removeClass('hover grayscale grayscale-fade');
    $(this).find('.post-link').show();

});
```

Comment: You might want to read this: http://www.majas-lapu-izstrade.lv/cross-browser-grayscale-image-example-using-css3-js/

Comment: **[This Link](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/grayscale-image-web/)** might be helpful

Comment: Thank you but I just need to figure out how to initialize the Gray plugin for IE11. I'm not looking to implement another method. I'm already confused enough as it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Here is an [updated example that works in IE11](http://jsfiddle.net/o0cvzfyf/) and all other supported browsers.

---

#### Exaplaination

There were a few issues...

According to [the plugin that you are using](https://github.com/karlhorky/gray#how-it-works), when the browser doesn't support CSS3 filters (like in IE10/11) the following applies:

> ...the plugin uses `Modernizr._prefixes`, `css-filters`, `Inline SVG` and `svg-filters` feature detects from Modernizr to determine browser support. If a browser supports inline SVG and SVG filters but not CSS filters, the plugin replaces the elements with SVG elements with filters.

Since the `img` element needs to be replaced with an SVG element in IE11, the plugin script (with [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) shiv) is required in order for it to work. In the jsFiddle example you provided, the script `jquery.gray.min.js` actually wasn't even being executed in IE11 since it was blocked due to mismatched mime types (this warning was in the console).

To work around this, I just copy/pasted the script into the example. In addition, it's worth noting that the [Modernizr docs](http://modernizr.com/docs/) state that the script ***must*** execute *before* the `<body>` loads. This seems to be relevant in IE when using a HTML5 Shiv:

> The reason we recommend placing Modernizr in the head is two-fold: **the HTML5 Shiv (that enables HTML5 elements in IE) must execute before the `<body>`**, and if you’re using any of the CSS classes that Modernizr adds, you’ll want to prevent a FOUC.

Now that the script is actually being executed in IE11, the plugin needs to be initialized and the `img` element needs to be replaced with an SVG. According to the plugin, the `img` elements will automatically be replaced if the element has the class `.grayscale`. Alternatively, it also looks like you can use the custom `.gray()` method, too. Since your example wasn't actually giving the class `.grayscale` to the `img` element, it wouldn't have being initialized in IE11.

Below, you will notice that I added the class `.grayscale` to the `img` element (in order to initialize it in IE11). In addition, the class `.grayscale-off` is also added to the element in order for the gray effect to be *off* initially. In the updated jQuery, you will see that this class is just toggled.

Here is the relevant updated HTML/CSS/jQuery:

[**Updated Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/o0cvzfyf/)

I also shortened the jQuery a little too:

```
$('#content').on('mouseenter mouseleave', 'article.project', function (e){
    $('.grayscale', this).toggleClass('hover grayscale-off');
    $(this).find('.post-link').toggle();
});
```

```
.grayscale.grayscale-replaced > svg {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease;
    transition: opacity .2s ease;
}
.grayscale.grayscale-replaced.grayscale-off > svg {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```
<div id="content">
    <article class="project">
        <img width="375" height="375" class="grayscale grayscale-off" src="http://lorempizza.com/380/240" alt="image-title" />
        <div class="overlay">
            <h3>Project Title</h3>
            <a class="post-link expand" href="...">+</a>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. You said, "Alternatively, it also looks like you can use the custom .gray() method, too." Would it be possible to show how to use this method without having the image initially gray on load? I couldn't figure that out.

Comment: @J82 It would be nice if that plugin had a callback or something that could be hooked into.. perhaps even options for the `.gray()` method would be helpful too.. It seems like this is the only way - `$('img').gray().addClass('grayscale grayscale-off');` http://jsfiddle.net/suvhm94g/

Answer (score 2):

IE prefers SVG to add filters on images.
Here is a way to achieve this on IE10, Firefox and Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/azx3mxmt/3/

Pictures are added programmatically like this:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var src = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3ab1c56fadd51711d1d94cc18aa37d8d?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG";
for (var i=200 ; i < 2200 ; i += 100) {
    container.appendChild(animation(src, i));   
}
```

SVG filters are set like this:

```
<svg width="128" height="128" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter" >
      <feColorMatrix id="gray" type="saturate" values="0.5"/>
    <filter/>
  </defs>
  <image x="0" y="0" width="128" height="128"
         filter="url(#filter)"
         xlink:href="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3ab1c56fadd51711d1d94cc18aa37d8d?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"/>
</svg>
```

Other effects can be achieved with SVG. Look at this [web site](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/hands-on-css3/hands-on_svg-filter-effects.htm).

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to implement this into the already existing [Gray](https://github.com/karlhorky/gray) plugin I'm using? According to the plugin, IE11 is supported but needs to be initialized.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with this plugin. You should ask directly to [karlhorky](https://github.com/karlhorky). You can give him my code : it's open source.